# Shadow appear on the middle of the character after the two part have been reunited

Tags: modeling

I make my character with the mirror and when i finished, I copied the first part, used mirror and reatached the to partie, but there is a wierd shadow now in the middle and i dont know how to remove it (i tried with sculpt to smoosh the surface but that didnt work.[image]

and i don't know if its linked but when i put the uv texture it's only appears on one side
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like the normals are messed up. Try using merge by distance and reset your normals

Comment: Have you selected clipping ?

Comment: i already used merge and i just tried to use the normals but that didnt do anything

Comment: i not really sure to understand what clipping is but that that doesn't seem to be the problem here (but i dont know its my first 3d creation)

Comment: Do you have internal faces ? In edit mode Select > Select all by trait > Interior faces